# Can I 'wear' more than one "hat" at the same time?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

It is nice to receive "hats" conditionally given out by SE. What if I have more than one hats?

Of course, a man cannot wear more than one hats at the same time because he has just one head. Even if he can, that will not look good.

The point I want to make is:-
If the objects given out were something (like other decorations) that can be put on simultaneously, it would be nicer/indicative/....

Comment: You can wear threehats at once. :)

Answer (score 2):

As T. Bongers noted, one of the hats is actually three hats.

But if you don't have that one, you can still wear multiple hats. It only takes a little Photoshopping. You can even **wear the same hat twice**:

[image: Shog9]

But with the built-in hat-adding script,   you can't do these things. The script is buggy enough without multiple hat support.

Comment: Glad to see some one responded to the post indicating the suggestion made is not that in-constructive.